# How to create an executable command prompt script

Tags: windows, command-line, executable

I usually perform actions in the 7zip command line program. I was thinking about creating a small script to do everything automatically, but I have never written any Windows shell script before and therefore don't even know where to begin.

I would like to make an executable script file which, when a user double-clicks on it, will call the 7zip command line and perform some actions.

First of all, is this possible? And if it is, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a batch script to do this.

It's basically command line commands that run one after another so you don't have to keep typing them in :)

Put the commands you would normally use for 7zip in a notepad file and save it with the extension `.bat`, then run it.

```
7z blah blah params
7z more params and args
```

All your commands will be executed automatically when the previous one finishes.

There are other programming languages you could do this in (or even VBScript) but batch would be perfectly suited to this, and you don't need to install anything extra.

Comment: No worries :) Yep you can set variables using `set myvar=7z` and use it using `%myvar%`.

Comment: So simple, yet works so perfectly for what I needed as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Batch files can run a series of command line commands. Simply create a text file and name it with the `.bat` extension.

There are plenty of resources on the internet which will provide you with help.